# Query Takes 30 seconds long

Tags: php, mysql

We have a registration system Database and basically what this query does is check the students that are in the class so that they can be selected to be marked as absent if they are absent.  For some reason, it takes 30 seconds.  Does anybody know why?

```
    FROM Stdts
    LEFT JOIN StdtReg ON StdtReg.StdtID = Stdts.ID
    LEFT JOIN usrs ON StdtReg.userID = usrs.ID
    WHERE (SELECT ID FROM ClssInstncEnrol cie WHERE cie.status = 0 AND classInstanceID={$_GET['ci']} AND StdtID = Stdts.ID LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
    OR (SELECT ID FROM DropIns di WHERE di.type <> -1 AND classInstanceID= {$_GET['ci']} AND StdtID = Stdts.ID LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
    AND (CONCAT(Stdts.firstName, ' ', Stdts.lastName) OR CONCAT(usrs.firstName,' ', usrs.lastName))
    ORDER BY firstName, lastName
```

Comment: Subqueries, calculations (CONCAT) on every row, and I'd bet insufficient indexes too.

Comment: Try doing an `explain` on the query, and see what indexes (if any) are being used.

Comment: This code should take zero seconds and throw an error immediately, for it is not a valid query :)

Comment: any query will take a long time if the tables its querying have enough rows.  Especially when you join them.

Comment: And there's a nasty SQL injection hole, too :) Never use variables from $_GET or $_POST directly in a query; always use mysql_real_escape_string first. Google SQL injection to see why.

Comment: It depends how much data are you dealing with. But I think that WHERE clause could be improved - it would be helpful if you posted your schema and included what is in the SELECT part of the query. You could also probably add indexes to improve the lookup. The CONCAT function could be moved to the SELECT and then used in a HAVING clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the query with "EXPLAIN " before it and it will tell you how each table is being joined and where you might be missing an index.

Also, you have an SQL injection waiting to happen with queries of this form with HTTP params interpolated directly in the query.

Finally, you've left off some of the query and the schema, but this strikes me as something that could be done with joins rather than subselects, or even as separate queries to generate the list of student ids more efficiently before you even run the main query.

Comment: This was my solution.  I still have to put in the mysql_real_escape_string but for now, I don't really use the search functionality in this query.  It was mostly because of the size of the table (over 5000 rows) is why the old query was so slow.  When I tested it with only a few rows in my test environment, it was fast.  Here is what I came up with with is really fast.  There may still be some errors but it works great.

Comment: SELECT Stdts.ID AS studentID, Stdts.firstName, Stdts.lastName, 
      usrs.firstName as ufirstname, usrs.lastName as ulastname,
      usrs.email1 as email, usrs.homePhone as home
  FROM Stdts
  LEFT JOIN StdtReg ON StdtReg.StudentID = Stdts.ID
  LEFT JOIN usrs ON StdtReg.userID = usrs.ID
  LEFT JOIN ClssInstncEnrol cie ON Stdts.ID = cie.studentID
  WHERE (
   cie.classInstanceID = {$_GET['ci']}
  )
  AND (CONCAT(Stdts.firstName, ' ', Stdts.lastName) LIKE '%$s%' OR CONCAT(usrs.firstName,' ', usrs.lastName) LIKE '%$s%')
  GROUP BY Stdts.ID
  ORDER BY firstName, lastName

Comment: It looks like it lost all the formatting so it's really hard to read.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  5000 rows is not a lot (I am querying 10,000,000 rows on modest hardware in less than a second).  You should examine EXPLAIN output and add indices accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the execution plan of your query to see what could be wrong (if you have huge tables and do not use appropriate index it can be long)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
AND (CONCAT(Stdts.firstName, ' ', Stdts.lastName) OR CONCAT(usrs.firstName,' ', usrs.lastName))
```

should be:

```
AND (CONCAT(Stdts.firstName, ' ', Stdts.lastName) = CONCAT(usrs.firstName,' ', usrs.lastName))
```

Comment: Not to mention, is there really a reason to concat the two, rather than just comparing them directly (firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname)?

Comment: Yes, that would be more sane. But the concat-thing might be there to correct for incorrect entries (where one of the two fields contains the full name).  Though, in that case I would problaby trim them first.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I left out part of this query when testing and forgot to add it again. That might be where the confusion was with the queery.  Here is the original last line that contains the LIKE and search string, which I know needs to be done with mysql_real_escape_string. <br> AND (CONCAT(Stdts.firstName, ' ', Stdts.lastName) LIKE '%$s%' OR CONCAT(usrs.firstName,' ', usrs.lastName) LIKE '%$s%')